# Firebase Deep Link short URL

Tags: firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

Can the links for Firebase deep links be shortened? Do they have that feature? Links generated are too long and that is not good.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**UPDATE**

**Firebase now supports shorten dynamic links [programmatically](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/short-links).**

I've faced the same problem getting a long and not user friendly URL when creating a dynamic link programmatically.

The solution I've found is to use the [Google URL Shortener API](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/apis/urlshortener/v1) that works brilliant.
That link points to the Java library, I'm using it in Android, but you can do also a simple http request.

I'll post my Android code in case you need it:

```
private void createDynamicLink() {
    // 1. Create the dynamic link as usual
    String packageName = getApplicationContext().getPackageName();
    String deepLink = "YOUR DEEPLINK";
    Uri.Builder builder = new Uri.Builder()
            .scheme("https")
            .authority(YOUR_DL_DOMAIN)
            .path("/")
            .appendQueryParameter("link", deepLink)
            .appendQueryParameter("apn", packageName);

    final Uri uri = builder.build();

//2. Create a shorten URL from the dynamic link created.

    Urlshortener.Builder builderShortener = new Urlshortener.Builder (AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(), AndroidJsonFactory.getDefaultInstance(), null);
    final Urlshortener urlshortener = builderShortener.build();

    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>() {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            Url url = new Url();
            url.setLongUrl(uri.toString());
            try {
                Urlshortener.Url.Insert insert=urlshortener.url().insert(url);
                insert.setKey("YOUR_API_KEY");
                url = insert.execute();
                Log.e("url.getId()", url.getId());
                return url.getId();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return uri.toString();
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String dynamicLink) {
            Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
            sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, getResources().getString(R.string.share_subject));
            sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, dynamicLink);
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, getResources().getString(R.string.share_using)));
            Log.e("dynamicLink", dynamicLink);
        }
    }.execute(null, null, null);

}
```

Hope it helps!!

Comment: URL Shortener is deprecated. Refer https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/apis/firebasedynamiclinks/v1 this link for firebase dynamic link

Comment: is it a must to shorten a deeplink? my link already a very small one?

Answer (score 2):

The links can be shortened in the Firebase console in the Dynamic Links tab. Tap on 'New Dynamic Link', which gives you an option to create a short link from an existing link.

Comment: But can we do that programmatically? if i want to share my link on Facebook, it will have long links

Comment: So why can't you generate the short link on Firebase console and share that link on facebook?

Comment: @user14202a Yes you are right - this cannot be done programmatically today. Filed a feature request. Watch out for more updates on this.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done programmatically using the Firebase Dynamic Links REST API, for example:

```
POST https://firebasedynamiclinks.googleapis.com/v1/shortLinks?key=api_key
Content-Type: application/json

{
   "longDynamicLink": "https://abc123.app.goo.gl/?link=https://example.com/&apn=com.example.android&ibi=com.example.ios"
}
```

See https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/short-links

And I just had to code it for Android - here's the code in case it helps someone:

at the top of the activity:

```
lateinit private var dynamicLinkApi: FbDynamicLinkApi

private var remoteCallSub: Subscription? = null // in case activity is destroyed after remote call made
```

in onCreate (not really but to keep it simple, actually you should inject it):

```
val BASE_URL = "https://firebasedynamiclinks.googleapis.com/"

val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.createWithScheduler(Schedulers.io()))
            .build()

dynamicLinkApi = retrofit.create(FbDynamicLinkApi::class.java)
```

then when it's time to shorten a URL:

```
remoteCallSub = dynamicLinkApi.shortenUrl(getString(R.string.fbWebApiKey), UrlRo(dynamicLink))
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(
                    { url -> Log.d("Shortened: $url") },
                    { e -> Log.e("APP","Error with dynamic link REST api", e) })
```

Don't forget to unsubscribe in onDestroy:

```
override fun onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy()
    remoteCallSub?.unsubscribe()
}
```

And here's the classes you need for the dynamic API:

```
interface FbDynamicLinkApi {
    @POST("v1/shortLinks")
    fun shortenUrl(@Query("key") key: String, @Body urlRo: UrlRo): Observable<ShortUrlRo>
}

data class UrlRo(val longDynamicLink: String, val suffix: SuffixRo = SuffixRo())
data class SuffixRo(val option: String = "UNGUESSABLE")

data class ShortUrlRo(val shortLink: String, val warnings: List<WarningRo>, val previewLink: String)
data class WarningRo(val warningCode: String, val warningMessage: String)
```

Comment: Is this java? I think is JavaScript.

Comment: This is Kotlin.

Comment: Thanks! I don't know anything about it.

Answer (score 1):

This cannot be done programmatically as of the moment.

Answer (score 1):

Try This , its working fine in my case,
https://firebasedynamiclinks.googleapis.com/v1/shortLinks?key=[api-key]

```
{
  "dynamicLinkInfo": {
    "dynamicLinkDomain": "peg3z.app.goo.gl",
    "link": "[Your Long Url Which you want to make short]",
    "androidInfo": {
      "androidPackageName": "com.xyz"//
    },
    "iosInfo": {
      "iosBundleId": "com.dci.xyz"
    }
  }
}
```

'Content-Type: text/plain'